# Force password reset of all users

Tags: mediawiki, password

Our MediaWIki 1.25 server was running *without* `$wgSecureLogin`. The installer did not copy the setting from `DefaultLogin.php`, and the setting was *not* secure by default. (Related WikiMedia bug T111135: [LocalSettings.php lacks wgSecureLogin, wgCookieHttpOnly and wgCookieSecure](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T111135)).

We need to have all users reset their passwords. MediaWiki.org has documentation on resetting a password if you know the user's name at [Resetting passwords](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Resetting_passwords). However, it appears to lack a "force all users to reset their password" setting or method.

Though I have root access to the server, I don't know the MySQL admin password. I hope there's a web based setting or PHP script that can be used to require all accounts to perform the reset.

How do I require a password change for all users?

Comment: The MySql user and password should be within the MediaWiki configuration files or a script somewhere. I know nothing about MediaWiki, but it would need the user account information to gain access.

Answer (score 2):

You can force a password change by running

```
UPDATE user SET user_password_expires = '19990101000000';
```

(This is not the same as a password reset as it will accept the old password one time. Less secure, more forgiving.)

If you cannot be bothered to look up the DB password, you can just use [`maintenance/sql.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Sql.php).

Comment: Thanks. Before we get into SQL command line, is there a high level script I can use to do it? It seems like it should be pretty popular since the settings are insecure by default, and *a lot* of folks should be in the same boat.

Comment: There isn't; why write a high-level script for a low-level operation? If you want to write one, it would be fairly simple (you can look at [`wrapOldPasswords.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:WrapOldPasswords.php) for inspiration) although not nearly as simple as a one-liner in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Can you perform a query?

```
UPDATE the_table SET password='UserNeedsToResetPassword';
```

Now all users' passwords dont work anymore. I choose plain text, because I cant think of a way that `sha1($_POST['pass'])` results in this ;) *(or whatever hash you use)*

Comment: You can just set it to an empty string which is how MediaWiki represents passwords internally. The drawback of that solution is that you lock out users who don't have a valid email address.

Comment: *"Can you perform a query?..."* - well, I don't really have the access needed at the moment. Plus, I'm not a SQL guy, so I try to avoid SQL altogether. Hence the reason I am looking for the PHP or script to run to do it.